# Проблема с кодировкой в POST-запросе

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, requests

В Python 3 формирую и отправляю POST-запрос:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os, json, codecs, requests

url = 'some_url'
payload = {
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Sóny",
    "parent_id": "",
    "permalink": "Sóny"
  }
}
r = requests.post(url,  json=payload)
```

На сайте слово `Sóny` отображается в виде `Su00f3ny`, а мне нужно чтобы было `Sóny`. Входная кодировка этого слова `latin-1`. Сайт просит в кодировке UTF-8.

Пробовал так:

```
'Sóny'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

Ошибка:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Подскажите, как мне решить эту проблему.

Comment: кодировка исходного кода в Питоне 3 является utf-8 (не обязательно coding объявление добавлять). У вас и так должно работать. Ошибка не в post() вызове. Можете для отладки: `'S\xf3ny'` строку подставить и убедиться, что результат не меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Попробовал отправить и проверить что на сервер попало. `Sóny` вернулся таким же:

```
import requests


url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

payload = {
    "category": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Sóny",
        "parent_id": "",
        "permalink": "Sóny"
    }
}

rs = requests.post(url, json=payload)
print(rs)
print(rs.json())
print(rs.json()['json']['category']['name'])  # Sóny
```

Comment: Да через "http://httpbin.org/post" все нормально. Сайт на который отправляю я записывает "Su00f3ny". Если я делаю отправку запроса из "Simple REST Client", то все в порядке, запись без искажений.

Comment: Эххх столько вопросов и переменных... Simple REST Client посылает как appllication/json? Есть возможность подсмотреть его запрос, включая заголовки (Header)? Тот сайт на другой стороне понимает utf-8? Кст, по поводу понимания сайта... Попробуйте в коде прогнать: `import json
print(json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False))
print(json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=True))`, заметили интересное?

Comment: Да, вот такая ошибка: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Не, там другое было, у вас в payload что-то странное лежит

Comment: print(json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=True)).

Comment: {"category": {"parent_id": "", "permalink": "Sóny", "name": "Sóny", "id": 0}}

Comment: У меня этого ошибку не вызывает. Мб ваша ошибка в другом месте происходит. Не знаю... А по поводу вашей проблемы, попробуйте посмотреть какой запрос формируется из "Simple REST Client" и повторить его

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо. Решение такое:`r = requests.post(url,  data = json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})`

Comment: Как я вам уже явно сказал, проблема у вас не в post запросе . В вопросе у вас и так правильный код уже: `requests.post(url, json=data)`. Ответ @gil9red также явно это демонстрирует.

Comment: Согласен. Но не хватало мелочей для данного сервера.

Comment: обратите внимание: `["\u0430"]` и `["а"]` json-документы это один и тот же список (проверьте с `json.loads`). Поэтому это не мелочь, если сервер работает с одним вводом и не работает с другим—сервер сломан.